# Trying to put HTML in email but it's not working?

Tags: php

```
        $body = "<p style=\"text-align:center;\"><img src=\"http://www.codefundamentals.com/images/logo.gif\" /></p><br /><p>CodeFundamentals.com has posted a new article titled: <a href=\"http://www.codefundamentals.com/blog/ " . $articleURL . "\">".$articleTitle."</a>.</p><br /><br />You are recieving this e-mail because you subscribed to our newsletter. To unsubscribe, please <a href=\"http://www.codefundamentals.com/unsubscribe.php\">click here</a> and fill out the form.</p>";
```

If I just do the `<img>` and then some basic text then it sends so I know the HTML is being accepted. Am I escaping characters wrong?

Comment: Don't use mail() for MIME-emails. mail() is pathetically useless garbage. use something like Swiftmailer or PHPMailer, both of which make sending mime-emails utterly trivial.

Comment: Didn't read the whole line (you really should split it a bit), but: You're escaping the `"` in front of your variable concatenation for `$articleURL`.

Comment: To test your quotes before attempting to send mail, see what doing `echo "<p style=\"text-align:center;\">....` looks like in your browser's source. You will be able to determine where you may have gone wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I removed both \ for my articleURL and I also noticed articleTitle had one as well. Updated code is on my original post. Still no email

Comment: You say still no mail and you've edited your question without `mail()` related codes. Are you running this on your own machine or hosted site?

Comment: @Fred-ii- good idea. I put open a test page and it looks just fine in source -both variables are being echod out just fine it seems. no weird characters missing etc.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I removed everythign except the content of the email since the only thign in question here is that variable it seems. I've tried with just <img> and text and it works - the MIME types are correct since I've gotten some HTML working so far. It's just when I extend the HTML into something complicated liek this, that it doesn't work.

to answer your question-a hosted site. codefundamentals.com. You can see the source of codefundamentals.com/blog/test.php to see how the email is echod out onto browser

Comment: I tested your full mail code (with success), yet had to comment out `$headers .= 'BCC: ' . implode(', ', $recipients) . "\r\n";` since it threw `Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in...` - I assume you've defined `$recipients`?

Comment: Yes Fred thanks for all the help and quick replies - turns out my messages were being auto sent to my spam folder . I was removing the HTML bit by bit until it was nothing and I still had nothing! SO i surmised taht it was being sent to spam since I KNOW the mail was working. Sure enough, 10 or so emails in there. Apologies for wasting your time.

Comment: Not a problem, just glad it was resolved. *Cheers* - and you're welcome.